# How to make this component looped in React (by counting the fat thact it receives props and does some calculation and has static titles)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component

I have the following 3 list items. Each of them uses the same component but different calculations:

```
<ListItem title={'Product 1'} tag={tag} calculatedVal={getCalculatedVal(props.data.price1, props.data.price2)}
isMore={props.data.price1 >= props.data.price2}
handleClick={open}
/>
<Underline />
<ListItem title={'Product 2'} tag={tag} calculatedVal={getCalculatedVal(props.data.price1, props.data.price3)}
isMore={props.data.price1 >= props.data.price3}
handleClick={open}
/>
<Underline/>
<ListItem title={'Product 3'} tag={tag} calculatedVal={getCalculatedVal(props.data.price1, props.data.price4)}
isMore={props.data.price1 >= props.data.price4}
handleClick={open}
/>
```

How can be this converted into 1 component with the loop?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your code where `tag`, `getCalculatedValue`, `color`, etc. are declared.

But here's a basic approach. Move your list item props into an array and use a map to render each list item.

```js
import ListItem from "./somewhere/ListItem";
import Underline from "./somewhere/Underline";
import { getCalculatedVal } from "./somewhere/getCalculatedVal";

const PRICES = ["price2", "price3", "price4"];

export const MyComponent = ({ data, ...props }) => {
  const listItems = PRICES.map((price) => {
    return {
      calculatedVal: getCalculatedVal(data.price1, data[price]),
      isMore: data.price1 >= data[price],
      key: price,
    };
  });

  return listItems.map((listItemProps) => {
    return (
      <>
        <Underline color={props.color} />
        <ListItem
          title={"Product 1"}
          tag={props.tag}
          handleClick={props.open}
          {...listItemProps}
        />
      </>
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: Is the following structure a good practice?

Comment: i can't speak to your specific data structures, but this is a well-documented method to render multiple components: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components